# Variable passed by reference and function called within itself

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

I have a function declared like `function build(array $data, SimpleXMLElement &$xml)` and within the function, under certain circumstances I have to call itself like this:

```
$subnode = $xml->addChild($key);
build($value, $subnode);
```

I tried to shorten it a bit by writing it like `build($value, $xml->addChild($key));` but I get the notice `Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in...`

Isn't there any trick to safely replace the two lines with the one-liner?

TIA

Comment: `SimpleXMLElement`s are *objects* to begin with, and changes to them will propagate to anyone seeing the object anyway, whether you pass by reference or not…?!

Comment: Are you implying that passing it by reference isn't necessary? Cause if that's the case, you're 1000% wrong...

Comment: Depends on what you’re doing and expect to happen, but yes, I’m implying that for certain use cases the reference may be unnecessary.

Comment: In this particular case by reference is needed. But anyway, there are cases where by reference is even defined in stock function... For example, I just came across another identical issue. I wanted to echo the last element of an array, and all that in a one-liner... I did it like this `echo end(explode(' ', trim($item['ITEM.MTRL_CCWEBCAT']), 2));` and I'm getting the same notice, even though it's working... So I suppose it's a matter of just suppressing the notice?

Comment: `end`'s main use is to *set the internal array pointer* to the end. For that it doesn't make sense to pass the result of an expression, since that array cannot be accessed by anything afterwards, so setting the array pointer becomes pointless. That `end` also returns the last element is a byproduct. That's why such notices exist, to point out to you that the code might not do what you think. So, no, it's not a matter of needing to suppress the notice.